# how to Hide the child columns in grid dynamically using ExtJS 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, extjs4

I need to hide the specific column in grid on load of grid. i.e., child columns. Even i use hidden: true is also not working.

```
Ext.apply(this, {
            store: App.mcmTaskStore,
            columnLines: true,
            columns: [
                { header: 'P', sortable: false, width: 25, dataIndex: 'Priority', renderer: priorityRenderer }, //false because it's H M L and it sorts alphabetically
                { header: 'START', sortable: true, width: 100, dataIndex: 'StartDateFormatted', hidden: true, renderer: this.mcmCustomRenderer},
                { 
                    header: 'Incoming Flights',
                    columns: [
                        { header: 'FLT', sortable: true, width: 80, dataIndex: 'IncomingFlightNumber', renderer: this.mcmCustomRenderer },
                        { header: 'ETA', sortable: true, width: 120, dataIndex: 'IncomingFlightEta', renderer: startDateCustomRenderer },
                        { header: 'CTY', sortable: true, width: 60, dataIndex: 'IncomingFlightStation', renderer: this.mcmCustomRenderer },
                        { header: 'GT', sortable: true, width: 50, dataIndex: 'IncomingFlightGate', hidden: true, renderer: this.mcmCustomRenderer}
                    ]
                },
                { header: 'END', sortable: true, width: 100, dataIndex: 'EndDateFormatted', hiddden: true, renderer: this.mcmCustomRenderer},
                {
                    text: 'Outgoing Flights',
                    columns: [
                        { header: 'FLT', sortable: true, width: 80, dataIndex: 'OutgoingFlightNumber', renderer: this.mcmCustomRenderer },
                        { header: 'ETD', sortable: true, width: 120, dataIndex: 'OutgoingFlightEtd', renderer: endDateCustomRenderer },
                        { header: 'CTY', sortable: true, width: 60, dataIndex: 'OutgoingFlightStation', renderer: this.mcmCustomRenderer },
                        { header: 'GT', sortable: true, width: 50, dataIndex: 'OutgoingFlightGate', hiddden: true, renderer: this.mcmCustomRenderer}
                    ]
                },
                { header: 'PAX NAME', sortable: true, width: 250, dataIndex: 'Name', renderer: this.mcmCustomRenderer },
                { header: 'COMMENTS', sortable: false, flex: 1, dataIndex: 'Notes', hiddden: true, renderer: this.mcmCustomRenderer},
                { header: 'AGENT NAME', sortable: true, width: 250, dataIndex: 'AgentName', renderer: this.mcmCustomRenderer },
                { header: 'TASK TYPE', sortable: true, width: 120, dataIndex: 'TaskType', renderer: this.mcmCustomRenderer }
            ],
            tbar: mcmTbar
        });
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You've written 'hiddden' with 3 'd' in some places. I bet that's where it doesn't work.

Comment: sorry.. If am use the proper hidden: true, its not working. can u please correct it

Comment: Look, [it just works](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2i8). And very well, with that; the use case has clearly been tackled by Ext's developers. You must have something funky in your code, but what? Hard to say without seeing the whole thing running...

Comment: ya now working fine. But when able to print using Ed spenser's grid printer to print the grid. it show the child column

Comment: Judging by the code of this plugin, it doesn't seem to account for hidden columns at all, that is even if the column is not in a group. But that's another question.

Comment: @rixo.. can you please correct it. am new to extjs. tell me how to proceed

Comment: pls help me how to proceed

Comment: That's an entirely different question. Feel free to create a new question add link to it in the comments here to bring my attention to it. Also, I see that almost all your questions don't have an accepted answer. That's unfortunate because that's an important piece in the StackOverflow mechanics...